# Can I install LAMP over an existing Apache?

Tags: 12.04, apache2, lamp

I'm setting up my first VPS, and I installed and configured Apache before I realized that there was the LAMP package to do that for me. Can I just run `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` or do I have to uninstall the existing Apache first? From what I read, uninstalling Apache can be a bit of a pain, so I'd rather avoid it if I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install lamp-server^` will install a bunch of packages. You will see something like this:

```
Note, selecting 'libdbd-mysql-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'tcpd' for task 'lamp-server'
Note, selecting 'libdbi-perl' for task 'lamp-server'
libaio1 is already the newest version.
libaio1 set to manually installed.
libwrap0 is already the newest version.
ssl-cert is already the newest version.
```

As you can see, if you already have a package already installed (via apt), it will not be installed again.